# How to fix read: connection reset by peer in docker?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-registry

I have restart the Laptop and try to up my containers and while I run docker-compose up I got this error

ERROR: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": read tcp 10.80.50.96:53290->18.215.138.58:443: read: connection reset by peer

Any one can help me?

I have trid to re-install docker but still have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change your DNS server, Technically try to connect to [registry-1.docker.io](https://registry-1.docker.io) with another IP address instead of 18.215.138.58.