# Docker pull results in tcp "connection reset by peer" error

Tags: git, docker

I am trying to pull the image using the docker pull command, as given in the description, but it results in tcp "connection reset by peer" error.. I dont think it is a proxy issue, since docker.io and other pulls are working fine.

$ sudo docker pull ghcr.io/nokia/srlinux
*Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: Get "https://ghrc.io/v2/": read tcp 10.10.213.22:53496->103.224.212.220:443: read: connection reset by peer
*

**Following is the curl and openssl outputs for the URL :**
$ curl -v https://ghcr.io/nokia/srlinux
*Trying 20.207.73.86:443...
Connected to ghcr.io (20.207.73.86) port 443 (#0)
ALPN, offering h2
ALPN, offering http/1.1
CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
TLSv1.0 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection reset by peer in connection to ghcr.io:443
Closing connection 0
TLSv1.0 (OUT), TLS header, Unknown (21):
TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS alert, decode error (562):
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection reset by peer in connection to ghcr.io:443*

$ openssl s_client -connect ghcr.io:443
*CONNECTED(00000003)
write:errno=104
no peer certificate available
No client certificate CA names sent
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 309 bytes
Verification: OK
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)*
$

I expect the docker pull to be successful.  I am able to pull the images from other container repositories and hence I suspect this issue is more related to ghcr or git.

I tried to find solution for this issue in various forums and couldn't find a solution.

Let me know if anyone can help me resolve this issue.

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/75876759/19452884 this really helps me